# Quickly returning to RootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Is there any way to quickly go to `rootViewController`? I want to remove all views from the stack & return to `rootViewController` without even bothering the sequence of views on top of it.

Comment: Which type of app you are creating, I mean tab bar based or any other?

Comment: Its a simple UIViewController based app. My root view controller is a subclass of UIViewController & then I use ModalViewController, UINavigationController based on the need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I think you need to dismiss presented model then you can pop all the pushed view controllers. As presented model would not be in the stack of the navigation.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Then you can pop to base view controller.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController:YES];
```

Answer (score 8):

From the docs:

> popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
> Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller >and updates the display.
>
> `- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`
>
> Parameters
>
> animated:
>
> Set this value to YES to animate the transition. Pass NO if you are setting >up a navigation controller before its view is displayed.
>
> Return Value:
>
> An array of view controllers that are popped from the stack.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I am coming from the background & from the app delegate I am calling [self.viewController popToRootViewController:NO]; but before going to background I presented a modal view controller from the rootViewController which was there even after coming from the background.

Comment: You mean `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` right? Not `popToRootViewController:`.

Comment: Yes its NSArray *anArray = [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];   NSLog(@"Popped View Controller=%@",anArray);     The log statement prints Null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
[self.viewController popToRootViewController:YES];
```